# how to get value in respon decode jwt and save sharedpreferences

Tags: android, arrays, json, jwt

I want to take the id value, the results above are the decoded results of the login response. the problem here is there is no response to the jwt token when sending as a header to the server, so I have an idea by decoding the jwt and want to retrieve the id value. but here I am having a hard time. the case here is JWT Token and the JWT decode has been saved in sharedpreferences. What if I want to take the id value in the decoded results

Code Decode JWT Token

```
                    token = sharedPrefManager.getSPToken();
                    try {
                        decoded = JWTParser.decoded(token);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_DECODE, decoded);
```

this result : https://prnt.sc/qlp75h

Answer (score 0):

could you use Gson.after getting value from pref convert into Json then you can take easily

Comment: do you mean Token Jwt converts using Gson? @ThavaSelvan

Comment: I have used Gson to convert JWT. get that response @ThavaSelvan